# prettier bracketSameLine set true is not working with self closing elements Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using prettier extension version 2.7.1.

I set some configurations, including bracketSameLine in true. in `setting.json` file.

```
{
    "prettier.bracketSameLine": true
}
```

Also I added others configurations:

[image: prettier configurations]

The description says "Bracket Same Line" if `true`, puts > of a multi-line and I set it in true in *Workspace* and *User* settings.

[image: Bracket Same Line]

However, when I format my Vue file with prettier the result is seems that is not working as I expect. Because the description also says "does not apply to self closing elements". What config is missing to apply to self closing elements?

INPUT:

```
<small id="helper id" class="form-text text-muted">A longish piece of text here</small>

<p
  *ngIf="this.parent.descriptors && this.parent.descriptors.length"
  class="post-meta">
  <span
     class="post-meta__item"
    *ngFor="let descriptor of this.parent.descriptors"
    >Another piece of text here</span>
</p>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<small id="helper id" class="form-text text-muted">A longish piece of text here</small>

<p *ngIf="this.parent.descriptors && this.parent.descriptors.length" class="post-meta">
  <span class="post-meta__item" *ngFor="let descriptor of this.parent.descriptors"
    >Another piece of text here</span
  >
</p>
```

EXPECTED BEHAIVOR:

```
<small id="helper id" class="form-text text-muted">A longish piece of text here</small>

<p *ngIf="this.parent.descriptors && this.parent.descriptors.length" class="post-meta">
  <span class="post-meta__item" *ngFor="let descriptor of this.parent.descriptors">
    Another piece of text here</span>
</p>
```

Just the character '>' in the same line. I don't want to have additional lines with just one character.

ANOTHER CURRENT BEHAVIOUR DONT EXPECTED

[image]

Comment: Suddenly its starting to work like this, same for me.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open your project folder in VSCode.
2. Create a .prettierrc file in your project's root directory if you don't have one.
3. Open the .prettierrc file and add this to it

```
{
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
  "bracketSameLine": true
}
```